# why does my datagridview not show any results?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I'm new to vb.net and am trying to display results from a mysql server in my datagridview. Can anyone maybe point out whats wrong with my code? Thanks in advance.

Leaving out my connection string for safety, but it does connect. And if I put a breakpoint in the code it does fill the dataset with the correct data

```
Dim con As New MySqlConnection("server=;user id=;password=;database=")
    con.Open()

    Dim adp As New MySqlDataAdapter("Select CONCAT(FirstName,' ',Surname) as Name, LeaveDaysAvailable as 'Leave Days Available' from leave_database.Employees;", con)

    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    adp.Fill(ds)

    dgvMain.DataSource = ds


    con.Close()
```

This is the result. No errors....
[image]

this is the result if i run the same query in mysql workbench

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `DataSet` doesn't contain data directly.  It has a `Tables` collection that contains `DataTable` objects and each of those contains data.  If you assign a `DataSet` to the `DataSource` property of your `DataGridView`, you need to also set the `DataMember` property to tell it which `DataTable` to get the data from.

The problem is, you haven't named your `DataTable` so you have nothing to assign to the `DataMember`.  This line:

```
adp.Fill(ds)
```

actually creates a `DataTable`, populates it and adds it to the `Tables` collection.  It has no name though, so you have no name to set the `DataMember` to.  You would need to name the `DataTable` first, e.g.

```
adp.Fill(ds, "MyDataTable")
```

and then you can set the `DataMember`:

```
dgvMain.DataMember = "MyDataTable"
dgvMain.DataSource = ds
```

The alternative is to just bind the `DataTable` instead of the `DataSet`, in which case you don't need a name:

```
dgvMain.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
```

The thing is though, why create a `DataSet` in the first place if you're just going to use one `DataTable`?  Simply create a `DataTable`.  You can then pass that `DataTable` to the `Fill` call and assign it to the `DataSource` property.

Comment: ok cool thanks :) i understand that part now, but how would i go by defining that? i know with comboboxes you set the value and display members, but how do i set the columns in the dgv?

Comment: cool :) if i want to go the datatable way what would i write?

Comment: thanks for your help. dgvMain.DataSource = ds.Tables(0) worked :) i left the dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true; in aswell :)

Comment: "if i want to go the datatable way what would i write". Instead of waiting for code to copy and paste, read the instructions and implement them.  There's nothing difficult there.  In fact, you would only need to change one work in your original code, although you should probably change a variable name too.

Answer (score 1):

dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

Else You have to add columns to data grid you can do it using designer file or from code like

```
DataGridTextColumn textColumn = new DataGridTextColumn(); 
dataColumn.Header = "First Name"; 
dataColumn.Binding = new Binding("Name"); 
dataGrid.Columns.Add(textColumn); 

DataGridTextColumn textColumn = new DataGridTextColumn(); 
dataColumn.Header = "Leave day available"; 
dataColumn.Binding = new Binding("LeaveDaysAvailable"); 
dataGrid.Columns.Add(textColumn);
```

Using designer this  will may  help you https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dyyesckz(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: There's no need to add columns yourself.  They will be added automatically by default when you bind, if you bind correctly.  You'd only need add the columns yourself if you wanted to bind at design time or you wanted other than the default columns, e.g. you wanted combo box columns.

Comment: Or you need dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

Comment: dgvMain.AutoGenerateColumns = True doesn't do anything different. still no results when i run

Comment: thanks for the help, but I've already did the special concatenated column names in the sql query. so was looking for a dynamic way to do it

Comment: `AutoGenerateColumns` is `True` by default so there's no need to set it. When you bind, a column will be created for each column/property of the data source automatically unless there is already a column with the appropriate `DataPropertyName` value.  By the way, your original code looks to be for a `DataGrid` rather than a `DataGridView`, or else it's not actually valid for any type of grid.